# How to enforce a unified build configuration?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, continuous-integration, nuget

We have a group of projects developed in a similar way using .NET/C#. We also have a common set of best practices in place, and would like to verify them using StyleCop and FxCop.

We would like to perform some kind of maintenance *once* for each solution, to enforce running StyleCop and FxCop with a predefined configuration.

I was thinking about creating a solution-wide NuGet package which modifies the build behaviour this way. Unfortunately, solution-wide packages [have been deprecated](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521)<sup>(and just maybe will be brought back in some undefined future)</sup>.

We have created a NuGet package that runs StyleCop and FxCop after a build, but because of the reason stated above it can be installed only on a project level. This is unacceptable, because during development developers will be adding new projects, and could forget to install the "build package".

Is it possible to unify our build configuration in such a way that:

- each solution is "configured" (e.g. NuGet package installed, some post-build event added, ...) only once, when the solution is created ;
- after that, *the build* is working consistently even if new projects are added to the solution ;
- *the build* is attached to, or substitutes Visual Studio's "Build" command ;
- new developer working on a project should need only to download the Git repository - no magic you-ought-to-know-that tricks
- the same consistent build behaviour is exhibited when building the SLN file through MSBuild (or possibly some other tool) on a CI machine

?

<sup>(Also, our best practices include fast unit-tests for every piece of code written - thus it would be convenient to "configure" our solutions to run unit-tests after each "Build" button-press in Visual Studio.)</sup>

Comment: have you considered [custom project templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)? You can define certain packages to be preinstalled, when a new project with that template is created.

Comment: @karann Nice idea, thanks! :) This however still does not guarantee that developers will use this particular template when creating a new project. From this point of view this is as good as reminding them to install the package.